# Trimming slashes from string c#

Tags: c#, string, trim

I have a string which, for some reason, sometimes looks like this: `string a = "\"C:\\Temp\\1.bat"`, and sometimes looks normal, like this: `string a = "C:\\Temp\\1.bat"`

How do I fin out if I need to trim the first two `"\` from the string or not, and trim it if necessary? In the end, I wish to be left with: `"C:\\Temp\\1.bat"` anyway.

Comment: Do you have the string right, or do you mean "\\c:\\Temp\\1/bat"?

Comment: you can define the string as @"C:\Temp\1.bat"

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
a = a.TrimStart('\"');
```

Incidentally, you don't want to remove the `"\` from the beginning of the string.  That's impossible.  What you want to remove is the `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your string is actually `"C:\Temp\1.bat` , the `\"` is the escaped form of `"`, so you only need to remove the first character!

```
string a = "\"C:\\Temp\\1.bat" 
string b = s.SubString(1);
```